# middleware not allowing me login on web guard

Tags: laravel, authentication, middleware

i Have three Users(Staff,Admin,Hr) ...using different guards for restriction.The other guards are working fine but the web guard which is the default and guard for staff(users) is not allowing me login neither is it giving any error.

Here's my Login function

```
public function logged(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|min:6'
        ]);

        if (Auth::guard('web')->attempt(['email'=>$request->email,
           'password' => $request->password]))
        {

             return redirect()->intended(url('/home'));
        }
        Session::flash('message','Invalid Login details');
        return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email','remember'));
    }

   Below is my middleware

    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
        {
            switch($guard){
                case 'admin':
                if(Auth::guard($guard)->check()){
                    return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
                }
                break;

                case 'hr':
                if(Auth::guard($guard)->check()){
                    return redirect()->route('hr.dashboard');
                }
                break;

                default:
                 if(Auth::guard($guard)->check()){
                return redirect()->route('home');
              }

            return $next($request);

            }
```

**below is my config/auth.php ** as requested

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],



'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'admin'=> [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],

    'admin-api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],

    'hr' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'hrs',
    ],

    'hr-api' =>[
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'hrs'
    ],
],



'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Admins::class,
    ],

    'hrs' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Hr::class,
    ],

    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you skip the guard and let it just use the default, so for `default:` do the following

```
if (Auth::check()) {
    return redirect()->route('home');
}
```

Comment: Update your question with the contents of ```config/auth.php```, specifically the ```defaults``` and ```guards``` keys.